# Full Screen Component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am now working on the component, which needs to be the size of full screen. But I don't want to write external CSS for this component because it is part of a very big project, so this is a one single component, do you have any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance!

**SOLVED**
Using 100vh directly in the component

Comment: Sounds that a job for a common function instead of a React component

Answer (score 1):

On your component you need to specify this:

```
<your-react-component width="100%" height="100%"></your-react-component>
```

make sure that your body is also was set this way

```
<body width="100%" height="100%"></body>
```

Comment: I avoided using this with body element, I did this with just using 100vh in component directly. And it works like magic! Thanks though !